# Converting int to arr. Keep getting error Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, int

I'm writing a program to test the validity of a credit number.  This is what I've written so far, and the first `if` statement that checks for the correct amount of numbers works, and will output Invalid if there aren't enough numbers. The second `if` statement does not work however and I'm not exactly sure why.  Whenever I input a number that satisfies both `if` statements, I get the error message:

**Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException: For input string: "44444444444444"

at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)

at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)

at Program1.main(Program1.java:9)**

Not sure if I'm completely wrong about the way to convert the int to an array or if it's something small and stupid.  I don't have a lot of experience in Java.  Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong or if there's a better way to do what I'm trying to accomplish?  Any insight would be helpful.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the credit number: ");
    int creditNumber = input.nextInt();

    // Converts int to array.
    String temp = Integer.toString(creditNumber);
    int [] arr = new int[temp.length()];
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++) {
        arr[i] = temp.charAt(i) - '0';
        counter++;
    }

    // Checks for correct amount of numbers.
    if(!(counter >= 13 && counter <= 16)) {
        System.out.println("Invalid.");
        System.exit(0);
    }   

    // Checks for type of card.
    if((arr[0] != 4) || (arr[0] != 5) || (arr[0] != 6) || ((arr[0] != 3) && (arr[1] != 7))) {
        System.out.println("Invalid");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    else
        System.out.println("Valid");
        System.exit(0);

    input.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

44444444444444 is too big a number to fit inside Integers. Since your input is beyond the range of an integer, you get an input mismatch exception. Consider using a long or bigint instead. I tried it with a long and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks, that got rid of the error message.  The second if statement still does not work properly.  It's supposed to print Invalid if none of those requirements are met, meaning it only must satisfy one of them.  However it only prints Invalid.  Any ideas of how to fix this?